# Analytics Tracking and SEO

Tags: seo, google-analytics, analytics, matomo

I'm using piwik on some of my websites and recently switched from google analytics. I find most of the stuff same on both analytics. But i always had this question in mind that what am i supposed to track other than these ?

- Bounce rate
- Referral sites
- Keywords
- Geolocation
- Periodic data(Month, year, week) for above factors

Any other SEO factors to be considered while tracking with any analytics software ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see your most popular types of referrals, that is, distinguish from websites to search engine links. Popular search engine keywords would show you're on the right track for getting organic traffic. If these are coupled with a low bounce rate, these types of referrals are actually more likely to link back to you without you trying.

The new visits vs. returning visitors is important in measuring visitor loyalty to the site. If your site only offers one important thing to be used and one thing only, this will discourage return visits.

Also, see what particular pages are getting the most visits and viewing time. If you have freedom of setting the content in these websites, take advantage of the popular subject matter and try to capitalize on that.

Answer (score 1):

Time > 5s vs Time < 5s, branding vs non-branding, returning vs new, num. pages that have at last 1 visit from search engines vs indexed pages (site:), etc
And most important: goal conversions.